# Can I register / track convertions from my UTM campaigns

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce

I currently got a couple of UTM campaigns setup with all the correct parameters to determine each campaign from another.

The converting goal on my homepage is when a visitors creates a user profile.

Can I add some analytics code on my converting page / globally, that will enable me to see if the user that clicked through my UTM campaign ended up creating the user profile?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to create a funnel path with your thank you page or registration completed page as the conversion page.

You would use the URL destination if it's a static URL, for more information read about Goals here http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1012040

Once you have Goals setup you can view which Campaign generated the most registrations.

Comment: http://www.seochat.com/c/a/Google-Optimization-Help/How-to-Track-Conversion-Rates-in-Google-Analytics/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to track if a visitor came to your page with special campaign related parameters in the URL, e.g. made with this [Google tool](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033863).

There is a description how to track such campaigns [here](http://blog.crazyegg.com/2011/12/02/track-conversions-google-analytics-campaigns/).